# Why does Grails Scaffolding plugin limits the amount of displayed properties?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, scaffolding

I am using Grails 2.4.2 and the scaffolding plugin 2.1.2 and noticed that dynamic scaffolding does only display up to 6 properties of a domain class in the `index.gsp`. The `index.gsp` contains a [line](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-scaffolding/blob/master/src/templates/scaffolding/index.gsp#L31) like this.

```
props.eachWithIndex { p, i ->
    if (i < 6) { 
       if (p.isAssociation()) { %>
<th><g:message code="${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label" default="${p.naturalName}" /></th>
<%      } else { %>
<g:sortableColumn property="${p.name}" title="\${message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.${p.name}.label', default: '${p.naturalName}')}" />
<%  }   }   }
```

So the question is why is this limitation and why is it hard coded? Should not it be configurable? Is the limitation bound to the default layout `main.gsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's limited like that is to prevent creating a list page that has so many fields returned in it that it's unusable.

Secondly, it is configurable. You can install the templates and change it. Or you can generate the view and edit the gsp.

However, I suspect you are asking why can't you define this as something within the domain class or project and not have to do either of the above. I'd say fork the plugin, add that ability, and make a pull request.

Comment: Hi Joshua. Yes I am looking for a more flexible solution. Installing the templates is not my favourite option since it makes my plugin upgrade process more complicated (I would have to merge future changes to my local templates). Second `props` does not respect the properties order defined in `static contraints` of the domain class. Forking seems to be the way to go. But where can I discuss the implementation approach of this change? Would that be `grails-dev-discuss`?

Comment: I can empathize with your plight about not wanting to install the templates, but in my experience the projects where I have done so it hasn't ended up being the issue that I felt it was going to be. That said, the Google group grails-dev-discuss is the right place to follow up about the scaffolding plugin.